# Why does this Variable Reassignment give n/a?

Tags: pine-script

This script saves without error but does not work as expected.

I do not understand why line 14 does not work

```
diff_c_sum := diff_c_sum + diff_c // this does not work, outputs "n/a", WHY?
```

but line 16 does work.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Variable Reassignment Error")

var float diff_c_sum = 0.0
var float diff_t_sum = 0.0
BTC = request.security("COINBASE:BTCUSD", "", close)
ETH = request.security("COINBASE:ETHUSD", "", close)
US02Y = request.security("TVC:US02Y", "", close)
US10Y = request.security("TVC:US10Y", "", close)

diff_c = BTC - ETH // this works
diff_t = US10Y - US02Y // this works

diff_c_sum := diff_c_sum + diff_c // this does not work, outputs "n/a", WHY?
//diff_c_sum := diff_c_sum + -0.01 // but this works
diff_t_sum := diff_t_sum + diff_t // this works


plot(diff_c_sum, title="diff_c_sum")
plot(diff_t_sum, title="diff_t_sum")
plot(diff_c, title="diff_c")
plot(diff_t, title="diff_t")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all instruments have the same history length. When a value is not available, `n/a` is returned. Any calculation with an `n/a` value results in `n/a`. You can account for this by using the [nz()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_nz) function, which replaces `NaN` values with zeros (or given value) in a series.

This will work

```
//@version=5
indicator("Variable Reassignment Error")

var float diff_c_sum = 0.0
var float diff_t_sum = 0.0
BTC = request.security("COINBASE:BTCUSD", "", close)
ETH = request.security("COINBASE:ETHUSD", "", close)
US02Y = request.security("TVC:US02Y", "", close)
US10Y = request.security("TVC:US10Y", "", close)

diff_c = nz(BTC - ETH, 0) // this works
diff_t = nz(US10Y - US02Y, 0) // this works

diff_c_sum := diff_c_sum + diff_c // this does not work, outputs "n/a", WHY?
//diff_c_sum := diff_c_sum + -0.01 // but this works
diff_t_sum := diff_t_sum + diff_t // this works

plotchar(diff_c_sum, 'diff_c_sum', '', location.top)
plotchar(diff_t_sum, 'diff_t_sum', '', location.top)
plotchar(diff_c, 'diff_c', '', location.top)
plotchar(diff_t, 'diff_t', '', location.top)
```

The reason why `diff_c_sum := diff_c_sum + -0.01` worked is because it doesn't include `diff_c` which contained an `n/a` value.

Tip: You don't need to plot a variable to 'debug' it's value. You can use [plotchar()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_plotchar) for that, to have it show up in the data window. That's described in [Debugging > When the script’s scale must be preserved](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html#when-the-script-s-scale-must-be-preserved).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question with a great explanation. It solved my problem.